# NLog Truncate StackTrace

Tags: logging, nlog

I'm trying to limit StackTrace lenght in Nlog (https://nlog-project.org/) message

This is my working format string

```
${longdate} #${uppercase:${level}}# ${when:when=level>=LogLevel.Error:inner=${callsite} ${callsite-linenumber}:else=} ${message} ${onexception:EXCEPTION \:${exception:format=message,StackTrace}}
```

I know there are a "truncate" parameter

```
${message:truncate=1000}
```

I have tried in many ways but never get the desired result (can't find any documentation or example)

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for `${left}`:

```
${onexception:EXCEPTION \:${left:inner=${exception:format=message,StackTrace}:length=1000}}}
```